# How to save javascript variable to database in Ruby-on-Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model

I want to save a javascript variable to database. I have seen numerous videos online but they all revolve around a 'Post' like a blog post where you put the title and body in two separate form fields. But what if you want to save a javascript variable without the use forms?

I'm thinking of doing a work-around where I would do what the videos does with

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.label :variable_name %>:
<%= f.text_field :variable_name %><br />

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And I would then programmatically insert the variable in the text field and press the submit button and hide the form with css.

But obviously I would prefer an easier way.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to really submit your form and data or just a show/hide effect? If you really want to save the data into a database, what database are we talking about?

Comment: You don't have to perform a POST request, but it does provide more security for the data sent than a GET request. You can perform the request with AJAX or by submitting the form. The variables can be appended to the destination URL (form action property) or hidden <input> elements can be added with "name" and "value" properties that are used to identify the parameter on the server. Is there a preferred method you would like to use?

Comment: Sorry I should've made it clear, i'm using Ruby-on-rails so its sqlite

Comment: Assuming you want to save the variable to the database in response to a user event (e.g., the user clicks on something), then just create an event listener (using, for example, JQuery) that makes a `POST` request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can use text_field_tag, and here is sample [reference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html)

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :variable_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :variable_name %><br />

  # use text_field_tag instead of f.text_field
    <%= text_field_tag 'my_var', "", class: "class_name" %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'my_var', "", class: "class_name", :readonly => true %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I gave you two samples and text_field_tag will generate html code below

```
<input type="text" name="my_var" id="my_var" class="class_name" readonly="readonly">
```

first text_field  will allow user to type value 
  incase you do not want user to change the value 
 
  but you can change it with javascript you can use readonly = true as second example above

meanwhile from your controller you can access it through params[:my_var] as sample below

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    var1  = params[:my_var]
    # here you can process var1 and you don't have to have a field for var1 in your database
    ...
  end
```